# Multi level inheritance in C

Tags: c

I want to achieve multi level inheritance in C where the base class is inherited as a pointer. For example:

```
typedef struct Shape_s {
    int s;
}Shape;

typedef struct Circle_s {
    Shape* base;
    int c;
}Circle;

typedef struct ColoredCircle_s {
    Circle* base;
    int cc;
}ColoredCircle;
```

I want pointers because I want to make the base class "private", no access to it.
I also want polymorphism - all functions that work with Shape must also work with the derived classes.
For example:

```
shapeDraw(shape);
shapeDraw((Shape*)circle);
shapeDraw((Shape*)coloredCircle);
```

The above examples works only with one level of inheritance. I can not figure out how to do it for more levels.

Comment: C doesn't have inheritance, classes, or derived classes. Perhaps you should look at `union`s.

Comment: This isn't inheritance, it's composition.

Comment: Inheritance by composition? @Barmar

Comment: If you use pointers, you need to use `coloredCircle->base->base` to get the `Shape`.

Comment: Your scheme doesnt work for a single level, let alone multiple levels

Comment: shapeDraw((Shape*)circle); doesn't work? It is the first field in the structure, why it doesn't work? @Caleth

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against this design approach as it's not how C works, it's not how people expect C to work, and it just makes a giant mess of things. If you want this, use C++. If you're using C, make it simple.

Comment: `shapeDraw(shape)` implies these things are pointers, a `Circle *` is not an object whose first member is a `Shape *`, it is a pointer

Comment: You *could* call it like `shapeDraw((Shape*)*(Circle*)*coloredCircle)`, but that is (rightfully) ugly as sin

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use pointers for the base structures. Just use structure inclusion to make the base structure a header of the current structure.

```
typedef struct Shape_s {
    int s;
}Shape;

typedef struct Circle_s {
    Shape base;
    int c;
}Circle;

typedef struct ColoredCircle_s {
    Circle base;
    int cc;
}ColoredCircle;
```

With your existing structure definitions, you need to follow the pointers to access the base structures.

```
shapeDraw(shape);
shapeDraw(circle->base);
shapeDraw(coloredCircle->base->base);
```

There's no way to hide the number of levels when doing it this way. You can't do it with just casting, because that won't dereference the pointers.

Comment: I was about to post the same. The first real job I ever did used this approach and it's still the cleanest OO system I've ever worked on and it was written in C! You can have a library of functions that take a Shape* and they will work on any of the other structs because the first item in each is a Shape.

Comment: I want the base classes to be private

Comment: You need to adjust your expectations as C does not offer such things.

Comment: @MartinChekurov They can't be private because the caller needs to be able to reference the intermediate `base` members.

Comment: @MartinChekurov in C, either everything is "private" or nothing is. You can omit a definition in the header to hide all the members

Comment: @Caleth I don't understand. The definition of the base class would be in the header Shape.h, than this header would be included in Circle.h. No?

Comment: `Circle_s` is a base class, too. It can't be private to the user of `ColoredCircle_s`, because it needs to use the `base` member to get to `Shape`.

Comment: @MartinChekurov No, the definition for all three would be in Foo.c, and there would be whatever (forward) declarations wherever you liked. Any other way isn't "private"

Comment: @MartinChekurov Pointers are far worse, by the way. Someone could mess around with them, possibly even setting them to `NULL` and memory management gets a night-mare (consider copying of types, deletion, etc). If you do it as proposed here there's just one single malloc/free for each dynamically created object – or just one single declaration for objects with local storage duration.

Comment: OK, but then for example in destroyShape(Shape* shape) I won't know if the passed argument is allocated on the heap or not, to free or not.. It might be allocated Circle on the heap or Shape in the stack..

Comment: You shouldn't call it on stack-allocated shapes. The same as any other data -- you need to know how it's allocated to know whether it's safe to call `free()`.

Comment: Or be consistent and always use dynamic allocation, so it's always safe to free.

Comment: @MartinChekurov You cannot know anyway. Even with pointers someone could have created the object on the stack: `Shape s; Circle c; c.base = &s;`

Comment: You should also use `destroyShape(Shape** shape)` so the destroy function can `NULL` the pointer after free. It's better to end up with a circle with a `NULL` shape than a dangling pointer that might later point to a reused memory location.